# How to perform aggregation & stored procedure like logic in HBase tables?

Tags: hbase

I am new to HBase. I have installed it and used its basic JAVA API for CRUD operations. My Hbase table has sole column qualifiers (lets say A, B , C , D ) which have numeric values and now I need to filter those rows which matches certain formula like A * B >= C (there can b more complex conditions here ) and then I need to take sum of values of column qualifier D of my result set.

How can I do this HBase ? 
In short how can I perform Stored Procedure type logic in NoSQL HBase ?

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [HBase Coprocessors](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/coprocessor_introduction). To be specific, Endpoint Coprocessor. You can think of it as stored procedures in SQL DBs. In order to use an Endpoint Coprocessor you need to build and install it on the server side and can then it invoke through HBase RPC.

In order to build and use an Endpoint Coprocessor, you need to :

- Have a new protocol interface which extends CoprocessorProtocol.
- Implement the Endpoint interface. The implementation will be loaded into and executed from the region context.
- Extend the abstract class BaseEndpointCoprocessor. This convenience class hides some internal details that the implementer need not necessary be concerned about, such as coprocessor framework class loading.
- On the client side, the Endpoint can be invoked by two new HBase client APIs:

  **Executing against a single region:**

  HTableInterface.coprocessorProxy(Class protocol, byte[] row)

  **Executing over a range of regions**

  HTableInterface.coprocessorExec(Class protocol, byte[] startKey, byte[] endKey, Batch.Call callable)

See the link specified above for more details.

HTH